# What were the primary instigatory forces behind the 2016 improvements to the Housing Act 2004’s rent repayment order regime?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-history

It is often cited what the reasons are behind the changes brought in 2016 to the regime. But which forces had brought the shortcomings that the regime was proving to have statistically and in practice to Parliament’s attention, such that it was moved to bring in the changes of 2016?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in general, the political reasons behind the approval of a law belongs to [politics.se].

Comment: @SJuan76 in general, yes, but where there has been court experience it may have a legal dimension for why it wasn’t working.